# Can I can bacon?

Tags: bacon, canning

This question is my wife's. Of course, I wouldn't want to save bacon for later.

I have seen commercial canned bacon for long term food storage and camping, etc.

Is it possible to can bacon at home? Does it have to be pressure canned or do the preservatives in the bacon make that unnecessary?

How is the taste/texture of bacon out of a can? It's not worth doing if it will end up unappealing.

Comment: Why can it? How long are you (is she) hoping to keep it for? Why not just freeze it?

Comment: @talon8- In general canning is helpful because it saves freezer space, doesn't need to be thawed, and stays good during a power outage. Many things are better frozen but some things- like beans and stew meat for example- are nice to have on hand in bottles.

Comment: I found a site that demonstrates canning it raw... 
http://www.tngun.com/how-to-can-bacon/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a little digging and ran into a [Backwoods Home Magazine article](http://www.backwoodshome.com/articles2/gay127.html) on canning bacon. It is apparently possible, even easy. Basically, the process seems to be: lay bacon strips on paper, put another piece of paper over them. Roll this up (and possibly fold it) and put the roll in a mason jar. 90 minutes at 10psi (I'm quoting here, I'm not a canner myself) and voila, canned bacon.

I found [one review from avclub.com](http://www.avclub.com/articles/taste-test-yoders-canned-bacon-and-oscar-mayer-ful,2481/) of a commercial canned bacon product. It was not flattering. Not even a little bit. I don't know what that says about the possible taste of home canned bacon, if anything.

Comment: Removed the shopping site and added an actual product review of a canned bacon product.

Comment: Wow. That review is very unflattering. That does greatly reduce my interest in the idea. Still if it is that easy to do I might just throw some in the next time I have the pressure canner out and see how it is homemade.

Comment: http://www.emergencypreparationforum.com/canned-bacon-the-review-1650.html These guys seem to like the canned bacon.

Comment: I wonder if vacuum packing would be a better solution - I had vaccum-packed bakkwa that was quite tasty, but I'm not sure about shelf-stability.

Answer (score 0):

Pig candy. Look that up for ways to do this. Once cooked lightly & coated. It can be stored in plastic sealed bags or jars. in a cool place. We use red cane sugar some salt, powdered hot peppers. For this. Canada makes something like this with maple sugar.  Not sure how she makes this. The hot pepper is Asian stile.

Comment: Can you actually describe what this product is rather than telling us to go search for it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this answers any questions about home-canning bacon.